# HTTPS GET / HTTP/1.1 request through Java socket

Tags: java, sockets, https

I am trying to request an HTTPS page using Java socket programming. The code I use is

```
PrintWriter s_out = null;

s_out = new PrintWriter(socketData.getOutputStream(), true);

String message = "GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost:stackoverflow.com\r\n";

s_out.println(message);
```

The response was:

```
HTTP/1.1301MovedPermanentlyLocation:https://stackoverflow.com/X-Request-Guid:b49f01e7-8c3f-4276-b9fe-e325684f0f88Content-Length:143Accept-Ranges:bytesDate:Mon,31Jul201707:15:48GMTVia:1.1varnishConnection:keep-aliveX-Served-By:cache-sin18033-SINX-Cache:MISSX-Cache-Hits:0X-Timer:S1501485348.066340,VS0,VE366Vary:Fastly-SSLX-DNS-Prefetch-Control:offSet-Cookie:prov=929f70a3-e93d-2948-7098-74624f7c4e3c;domain=.stackoverflow.com;expires=Fri,01-Jan-205500:00:00GMT;path=/;HttpOnly<html><head><title>Objectmoved</title></head><body><h2>Objectmovedto<ahref="https://stackoverflow.com/">here</a>.</h2></body></html>
```

I don't know the syntax to request

https://stackoverflow.com in `GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost:stackoverflow.com\r\n`,

Can you please suggest what is the syntax to invoke https page?

Thanks.

Comment: Is there any reason why you're using plain `Socket` for this task? There are plenty of "high level" java APIs for making HTTP requests

Comment: well, first off, and not sure if relevant, you have to be using SSL-Socket not normal socket, because there should be other steps to perform, which is performed for you -by SSL socket- like handshake, key exchange, ... right?

Comment: @Yazan: yes.  When accessing an HTTPS url, you have to use an `SSLSocket` and perform the SSL/TLS handshake before you can then exchange any HTTP-related data.

Answer (score 0):

The request looks «quite correct», but it seems an unsecure connection is being used instead of secure one.

## Connection-based implementation

First of all, please consider using a higher level abstraction like the [`HttpsURLConnection` (Java Platform SE 8)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/net/ssl/HttpsURLConnection.html) class.

Please take a look at the implementation of the `useHttpsConnection()` method.

## Socket-based implementation

To establish HTTPS connection the [`SSLSocket` (Java Platform SE 8)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/net/ssl/SSLSocket.html)
 class should be used indirectly: the instance can be created using the [`SSLSocketFactory` (Java Platform SE 8)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/net/ssl/SSLSocketFactory.html) class.

Please take a look at the implementation of the `useSslSocket()` method.

## Draft source code (Java 8)

```
package com.brunov.test.console;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.URL;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import javax.net.SocketFactory;
import javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory;

public class Program {
    public static void main(final String[] args) throws IOException {
        useHttpsConnection();
        useSslSocket();
    }

    /**
     * Connection-based implementation.
     */
    private static void useHttpsConnection() throws IOException {
        final URL url = new URL("https://stackoverflow.com/");
        final HttpsURLConnection connection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setRequestMethod("GET");

        try (final InputStream inputStream = connection.getInputStream()) {
            final String response = readAsString(inputStream);
            System.out.println(response);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Socket-based implementation.
     */
    private static void useSslSocket() throws IOException {
        final SocketFactory socketFactory = SSLSocketFactory.getDefault();
        try (final Socket socket = socketFactory.createSocket("stackoverflow.com", 443)) {
            final String request = "GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nConnection: close\r\nHost:stackoverflow.com\r\n\r\n";

            final OutputStream outputStream = socket.getOutputStream();
            outputStream.write(request.getBytes(StandardCharsets.US_ASCII));

            final InputStream inputStream = socket.getInputStream();
            final String response = readAsString(inputStream);
            System.out.println(response);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Helper method.
     * Read a stream to the end into a string.
     */
    private static String readAsString(final InputStream inputStream) throws IOException {
        final ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        final byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int bytesRead;
        while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            outputStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
        }
        return outputStream.toString(StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name());
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Is there any way to get response from a different end point other than the actual host URL using the Socket-based implementation? (i.e.) a response from say stackoverflow.com/questions

Comment: Dear @Pervez, Yes, there is a way: use the appropriate HTTP request (please, refer to the `final String request` variable).